# CS50 Scrabbles like game

Tags: c, cs50

I am doing the CS50 scrabbles like game. I am doing the free version so we don't really get any feedback from our labs etc.
I wrote the code for this lab and it seems to work, but it's too ugly and I would appreciate some advice with it.
I am still learning so it's hard for me to tell if the good is actually right or not.
`

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    // Print the winner
    if (score1 > score2)
    {
        printf ("Player 1 is the winner");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Player 2 is the winner");
    }
}

int compute_score(string word)
{
    char A = POINTS[0];
    char B = POINTS[1];
    char C = POINTS[2];
    char D = POINTS[3];
    char E = POINTS[4];
    char F = POINTS[5];
    char G = POINTS[6];
    char H = POINTS[7];
    char I = POINTS[8];
    char J = POINTS[9];
    char K = POINTS[10];
    char L = POINTS[11];
    char M = POINTS[12];
    char N = POINTS[13];
    char O = POINTS[14];
    char P = POINTS[15];
    char Q = POINTS[16];
    char R = POINTS[17];
    char S = POINTS[18];
    char T = POINTS[19];
    char U = POINTS[20];
    char V = POINTS[21];
    char W = POINTS[22];
    char X = POINTS[23];
    char Y = POINTS[24];
    char Z = POINTS[25];
    
    int score1, score2;

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
    {
        score1 = 0;
        score1 = word[i] + word[i + 1];
    }
    return score1;
    
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
    {
        score2 = 0;
        score2 = word[i] + word[i + 1];
    }
    return score2;
    
}`
```

Thank you

Comment: For feedback on working code the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site would be better suited.

Comment: What is the point in these `'A'`..`'Z'` variables? They are not used. `POINTS` array is not used too, so it is not clear to me how you claim it is working.

Comment: `return score1;` Functions end whenever a `return` is encountered. That is, everything after that line in the function is dead code that never runs.

Comment: BTW, alot of these issues will be flagged by many compilers as warnings. You may need to turn up the warning level if you are not seeing such warnings. Since you are seeking feedback, always heed what the compiler tells you.

Comment: Hint: 'A' is a char and you can perform arithmetic on it. `scores[26]={..., ..., ...};` then just write a function that returns an index based on that. Just `static unsigned char letter_to_index(char letter) { return letter - 'A'; /* add error management */ }`, and then you can access scores like `score[letter_to_index('A')]`. Another solution is an array of structs with a letter and a score, but you'd still have to manage an index. Another solution is a hash table from letter to score, you could do that with a has table implementation like the one in the glib from the GNOME project.